# Investigate if the following polynomial in Q[x] is reducible or irreducible: $x^3-5x^2+2x+1$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Investigate if the following polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$ is reducible or irreducible: $x^3-5x^2+2x+1$.

Attempt:

$x^3-5x^2+2x+1\bmod 2$ we get $x^3+x^2+1$.

We see that the polynomial is of degree 3, so it is reducible if it has a root in $\mathbb Q$, using rational root theorem in $\mathbb Q$, we see there is no root in $\mathbb Q$, so it's irreducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already calculated, the polynomial $\bmod 2$ is of the form $x^3+x^2+1$.

If this was reducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, it would also be reducible $\bmod 2$. As you have already noted if it is reducible, it must have a root in $\mathbb{Q}$. But more importantly, if it is reducible, it must also have a root $\bmod 2$. This is because the polynomial is of degree $3$.

So $\bmod 2$ we only have to try two values: $1$ and $0$. Both are no root, thus it is irreducible $\bmod 2$. Then from it follows that it's also irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The claim "*If this was reducible in $\mathbb Q$, it would also be reducible $\bmod 2$*" needs to show that reducible over $\mathbb Q$ implies reducible over $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

By the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) the polynomial has no root over $\Bbb Q$ and hence is irreducible. This is probably the most direct way.

Answer (score 1):

A reducible polynomial must be a product of two non-constant polynomials with lower degree.  In particular, a reducible cubic polynomial has a degree-one and a degree-two factor.  Having a degree-one factor is equivalent to having a root.
You've correctly applied the rational root theorem to conclude the absence of rational root for the cubic polynomial in the question, so it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.